# Firebase Messaging With Spring Boot:Unknown error while making a remote service call: Unexpected error refreshing access token

Tags: spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am currently trying to use FCM in spring boot to send push notifications to android app. However, I get this error "**Firebase Messaging With Spring Boot:Unknown error while making a remote service call: Unexpected error refreshing access token**".
I have tried creating a different firebase project, and trying with it.
I am creating a Spring Bean for Initializing and Getting Instance of `FirebaseMessaging`. I have also checked if my service account has relevant permissions, and it seems to be fine.

This is the maven repository I am using for firebase admin-sdk.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my Spring Bean that initializes the firebase.

```
@Bean
FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(new ClassPathResource("firebase-service-account.json").getInputStream());
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions
            .builder()
            .setCredentials(googleCredentials)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions, "<project-name-here>");
    return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(app);
}
```

I have debugged, and there is no problem with the path of `firebase-service-account.json` file. The app is initialized correctly.

Then I am using this to send messages in my app in the following manner:

```
@Component
public class FirebaseNotificationHandler implements NotificationHandler {

    @Autowired
    private FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;


    public String send(Note note) throws FirebaseMessagingException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Notification notification = Notification
                .builder()
                .setTitle(note.getSubject())
                .setBody(note.getContent())
                .build();

        Message message = Message
                .builder()
                .setToken(note.getToken())
                .setNotification(notification)
                .putAllData(note.getData())
                .build();

        return firebaseMessaging.sendAsync(message).get();
    }

}
```

I have already spent hours trying to fix it but with no luck.